# Chrome App: Chrome app use USB API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm developing an app that should open a new tab automatically when a USB device is connected.

But I have a problem with the USB device. How can I know my app "catched" USB and how to add an event for it?

Comment: You can't. There's a USB API for Chrome **Apps**, but it's not exposed to extensions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how can I do with Chrome App?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently still impossible to do so in an event-based fashion.

You can instead [poll `chrome.usb.getDevices`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb#method-getDevices) on an interval from an app's background page, and see if it returns what you need.

Note: you will need VID/PID of the USB device in question, you cannot [indiscriminately detect devices](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb#manifest).

Comment: yes. I used it. But how can I know getDevices is worked?

Comment: Read the docs? [USB Devices](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb#finding_device)